# How to present a setup screen from my app delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a first time setup screen that I wish to present only on the first time run of the application. I have a tab bar controller with 5 tabs and an independent view controller that will appear on the initial run. After clicking a UIButton on the setup screen, it has return to the tab bar navigation with the first tab being shown. So far in my app delegate I have this:

```
// Override point for customization after application launch.

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"First Time"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"First Time"] == YES)
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"First Time"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


    SSSetupScreenViewController *setupController = [[SSSetupScreenViewController alloc] init];
    [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:setupController animated:NO];
```

However, this just brings a black screen every time the app is launched. Probably something simple I am missing, but help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set it to YES in the beginning since it will do that also the second run.

How about the following?:

```
// Override point for customization after application launch.

if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"First Time"] == nil)
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"First Time"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


    SSSetupScreenViewController *setupController = [[SSSetupScreenViewController alloc] init];
    [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:setupController animated:NO];
```

Comment: I got that down now; however, the app will still show a blank screen when ran for the first time. It won't load the view. Could it possibly be because it has no official connection to anything in the storyboard?

Comment: It might be, it is hard to give you any more advice based on the question details